# Memory Analyzer Tool

Tags: java

I was using MAT to analyze Heap Dumps. The problem is, we have 4 server legs supporting the application. And the heap dump for each leg gives different analysis report. Moreover heap dumps on the same leg, taken on different days, give different analysis report. How should I analyze memory leak issue in such situation?

Comment: here what is mean by 4 server legs? is your application deployed in 4 web servers (i.e. example wblogic).

Comment: want to know about how many total/used/free space out of total allocated memory to Java Heap ?

Comment: mallikgm: Yes, our application has one jvm, which in turn is extended by 4 application servers. To analyze memory leak, I have to take heap dumps from all the servers. But I am not able to recognize any common pattern among the analysis report generated by them.

Comment: -Vishal: As per one heap dump, total space: 770mb, used 530 mb. This space has been used by a single component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to monitor the servers for long time and analyze memory usage pattern where GC prints in the logs or high memory usage, (it'd be when more users hit the server) once you find the pattern when/where GC kicks, you can take a dump of snapshot and analyze it.

Dumps taken at different intervals at different servers (even if same server) will not be same, each server having its own resources like memory,processors etc